# Accessing query values in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js app and trying to create infinite scroll and search input.

Infinite scroll will load 6 more items when ever the user reach the bottom of the page. Search input will filter the results and will return only items with the string input in their title.

Both of the feature works fine alone, the problem is combining them.

The issue stages are:

1. enter search input - e.g. `"a"`
2. scroll to the bottom of the page

**Expected:** More results with the `"a"` search filter on.

**Actual:** `search` is an empty string, so no filter is on the results.

When debugging the `scrollHandler` function, `search` prop is an empty string, even when search param present in the URL query.

`getServerSideProps`:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const search = query.search || '';
  const limit = query.limit || process.env.ITEMS
  const params = {
    limit,
    skip: process.env.Items_INIT_SKIP,
    orderBy: process.env.Items_INIT_ORDERBY,
    search
  };
  const { data: items } = await getItems(params)
  return { props: { items, search, limit } }
}
```

`ItemsPage` component:

```js
const ItemsPage = ({ items, search, limit }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      const newLimit = 6 + Number(limit);
      const path = search ? `${router.pathname}?search=${search}` : router.pathname
      const query = { ...router.query, limit: newLimit, search }
      router.push({
        pathname: router.pathname,
        query
      },
      path)
    }
  }

  const searchHandler = e => {
    const search = e.target.value

    router.push({
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: {
        search
      },
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className={st(classes.root, {})}>
      <Input className={classes.Search} value={search} label='search' type='text' onChange={searchHandler} />
      <Items items={items} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ItemsPage;
```

Comment: Props from `getServerSideProps` are only loaded on initial page render. After that, it is not updated. Try `const path = router.query?.search` instead and see if that works.

Comment: hey @jdaz , sorry for the delay. i tried your suggestion it was still empty string. it doesn't need to be updated, the search is in the query params in the url, when the page render next doesn't see it ? currently the only solution i see is to extract it from the window object, but it doesn't feel right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the component to `class component`, and using the HOC: `withRouter` solved the issue, and allow access to the query params, and in the props.

```
class ItemsPage extends React.Component {

    scrollHandler = () => {
        if (Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            const { router, limit, search } = this.props
            const newLimit = Number(limit) + Number(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ITEMS_TO_ADD)
            const path = search ? `${router.pathname}?search=${search}` : router.pathname
            const query = { limit: newLimit, search }
            router.push({
                pathname: router.pathname,
                query
            },
                path)
        }
    }


    searchHandler = e => {
        const { router } = this.props
        const search = e.target.value
        const path = search ? `${router.pathname}?search=${search}` : router.pathname
            router.push({
                pathname: router.pathname,
                query: {
                    search
                },
            }, path)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler)
    }

    render() {
        const { Items, router } = this.props
        const { search } = router.query
        return (
            <div className={st(classes.root, {})}>
                <Input className={classes.Search} value={search} label='search' type='text' onChange={this.searchHandler} />
                <Items Items={Items} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(ItemsPage)
```